# Button "Add" is disabled in VPN Connection's dialog

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I've just installed elementaryos-jupiter. (It's based on Ubuntu 10.10)

I've entered VPN Connections' menu (nm -> VPN Connections -> Configure VPN)

And there should be button "Add" -> it is, but it's disabled (I can't press on it)

I'm connecting via ethernet (LAN in a students' hostel) and we get internet via VPN connection (It worked for me in Ubuntu for a few years)

Any suggestions?

I've asked on IRC of elementaryos (there were few people) but they said that VPN is out-of-box, and it should work - they never met this.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to remember running into a similar issue a while back. In my case at least, the root cause was that my Ubuntu 9.10 install was missing a bunch of Network Manager plugins. Searching for network manager plugins using apt give me the following list (again on a 9.10 install):

> network-manager-openconnect - network management framework (Openconnect plugin)
>   network-manager-openvpn - network management framework (OpenVPN plugin)
>   network-manager-pptp - network management framework (PPTP plugin)
>   network-manager-strongswan - network management framework(strongSwan plugin)
>   network-manager-vpnc - network management framework (VPNC plugin)

Maybe it would be worth verifying that the plugin matching whatever type of VPN service you're trying to use is installed.